# JButton dynamic tooltip text not showing

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jbutton, jcomponent

I want to have a dynamic tooltip for my `JButton`, so I used something like this to overwrite the `getToolTipText()` method...

```
JButton myJButton=new JButton("My Button"){
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent evt){
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay(100);
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(60000);

        return "Test Tip Here";
        }  // Return plain text now, will be replaced by calculateTipText() later
    };
```

When I have this code, no tooltip is being displayed at all.

However, if I add another line like this...

```
myJButton.setToolTipText("Hi");
```

After this point, the tooltip will be displayed correctly as `Test Tip Here`.

Why doesn't my tooltip work until I call `setToolTipText()`?

Comment: Well, you override the default implementation. It's doing exactly what you told it to do: return `Test Tip Here`.

Comment: http://www.michaelwilliams.co.za/simple-dynamic-tooltip-text-for-jcomponents-2/ hope it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setToolTipText()`, listeners are registered on your `JButton` that allow the tooltip to be displayed. These listeners are only registered on the `JButton` when you call `setToolTipText()`, because there's no use listening for tooltips on all `JButton`s when only a small subset of them actually have a tool tip value set.

Overwriting the `getToolTipText()` method will return the `String` you specify, but only after you register the listeners on the `JButton` first (by calling the `setToolTipText()` method).

Refer to the `JButton` source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.setToolTipText%28java.lang.String%29) where you can see that it sets the value and then registers the listeners in the `ToolTipManager`. You may be able to register the listeners yourself to achieve what you want, such as by calling this after you create the button...

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(myJButton);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, I didn't expect this behavior, I thought when I declared my JButton as above, it should auto register a listener. I modified my code from a JList I had, which auto registered a listener when I declared it similar to above. It's smart enough to detect that.